# Why is this macro copying multiple times?

Tags: excel, vba

I found this macro and it does what I need it to do however whenever it's activated it seems to copy/paste the data multiple times.  My master list should only have 75 or so lines and when this runs it ends up at 268. Why is it doing that? Also, is there a way to edit it so if a sheet has no data in it after "A1" it doesn't copy that sheet?

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

'Merge all sheets in a workbook into one summary sheet (stacked)
Dim cs As Worksheet, ws As Worksheet, LR As Long, NR As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set cs = Sheets("Master List")
cs.Activate
Range("A2:F" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

For Each ws In Worksheets
    If ws.Name <> "Master List" Then
        NR = cs.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        LR = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        ws.Range("A2:F" & LR).copy cs.Range("A" & NR)
    End If
Next ws

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: TO skip a WS with that has no data in cell A1, change the conditional to: `If ws.Name <> "Master List" And isempty(ws.Range("A1")) = False Then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this in the `Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()` event of the workbook. If this is written into the "Master List" sheet's code, then activating the sheet as you do with line `cs.activate` will trigger the macro again... the one that is currently running. It's hard to say why this only creates 268 and not infinite, or double... it's tough to say and may be dependant on the speed at which excel works and it's single threadiness or some other deep down dark mystery of Excel and VBA.

Instead of

```
cs.activate
range("a2:f" & rows.count).clearcontents
```

try

```
cs.range("a2.f" & rows.count).clearcontents
```

If you find yourself writing `.activate` or `.select` in your vba code, you are probably doing something not-so-great.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I made your suggested edit but the end result is the same. It also doesn't seem to be duplicating in order.  I'm going to create a whole new workbook and see if the same thing happens. EDIT: I think I figured it out, the sheets are all out of order on the VBA list Just going to copy all the data to a new workbook with the sheets in order.

Comment: The order of the sheets shouldn't make a difference. The code is either looping through every sheet and grabbing it's data or it isn't. EDIT: I see that's being in order is important for your needs. My mistake.

Comment: follow up: same thing, it will copy sheet 1 then 3 then back to 1...I'm not concerned with the order of the data on the master sheet because that can be filtered, it's just that the data gets duplicated

Comment: Just to be certain before I tear my hair out trying to figure this one out, you, for sure, took out the `cs.activate` line. An you can confirm that there are no other `active` or `select` code in there? Is there any other code in other worksheets that are triggered by `worksheet_activate` or any other similar type of event?

Comment: @JNevill weird, I used the exact code, added code to the 'Master List' sheet's code and work as expected.  No dupes.

Comment: I am positive, here is what I just did though. I went through and labeled everything in column A with an alphanumeric designation instead of just the numeric designation like it had before, ran the code and it pulled the new alphanumeric ones like it should but also the old numeric ones somehow.

Comment: I just noticed that the numbers aren't lining up. It also added more alphanumeric designations in column "A"

Comment: Make sure you delete all of the existing values out of "Master List " before running the code. Also, maybe taking that code out of the worksheet_activate event and just fire it off by hand until you get this debugged.

Comment: I got it to work, took all the data from the workbook and made a new one. I don't know if this caused the issue but the sheets in the first book weren't all 1 through whatever; they had a lot of previously deleted rows.  A fresh workbook with all the rows there seemed to fix it.  Thank you for your help!